# [merg.it]... Sorry, I mean [repl.it]. Or is it [replit]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Both [repl.it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repl.it) and [replit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/replit) seem to be about the same subject: [Replit](https://replit.com), formerly known as [Repl.it](https://repl.it) [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replit).

I suppose we should merge them, with [replit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/replit) as the target (i.e. synonymize [repl.it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repl.it)) since that is the current name of the company/platform.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, this one seems about as clear as a merge could possibly ever be.  Tags merged (target tag: [replit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/replit)) and synonym between them created.

```
updating post history, 341 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 318 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 313 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'repl.it': [repl.it] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 676
tag remapping of [replit] and [repl.it] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
101 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
5 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym repl.it -> replit was approved!
```

Comment: I feel like any tags that only differ by periods or hyphens should be merged (unless there's a [c--] programming language out there).

Comment: @Laurel That might be a good SEDE query...

Comment: @Laurel [This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1783298) (written by ChatGPT) probably did the trick. There are a few false positives though: [tag:.d.ts]/[tag:dts], [tag:.mov]/[tag:mov], [tag:app-code]/[tag:appcode], etc.

Comment: @InSync Fantastic, thank you; I'll probably put up an MSO post at some point to handle those in bulk, unless someone beats me to it.